# Coloring the switchboard red

Tags: code-golf, grid, path-finding

### Question

> If you are currently on a cell with a value x, you can move to any
>   cell in the same row or column, provided it has a value y such that x > 
>   y. This move is called a **switch**.

The **input** consists of:

- two integers 0 < m,n < 50
- an integer k indicating the number of switches allowed 0 < k < 20
- an m by n grid filled with integers in the range -128 to 127

The **output** consists of:

- a single integer r, indicating the minimum number of cells that have to be coloured red to satisfy the condition.

The **condition** is that:

- if any cell is selected on the switchboard, it must be possible to

  - start at any red cell of your choice
  - make upto k switches
  - end up at the selected cell
- the output must be reached within **60 seconds** using any amount of memory.

### Sample data

**Inputs**

```
(a) 7 8 10 
55 25 49 40 55 3 55
33 32 26 59 41 40 55
31 23 41 58 59 14 33
9 19 9 40 4 40 40
55 54 55 46 52 39 41
10 41 7 47 5 30 54
40 22 31 36 7 40 28
21 40 41 59 14 36 31

(b) 9 8 10
50 98 54 6 34 94 63 52 39
62 46 75 28 65 18 37 18 97
13 80 33 69 93 78 19 40 13
94 10 88 43 61 72 94 94 94
41 79 82 27 71 62 57 67 34
8 93 2 12 93 52 91 86 93
94 79 64 43 32 94 42 91 9
25 73 29 31 19 70 58 12 11

(c) 10 9 10
50 54 6 34 78 63 52 39 41 46
75 28 65 18 37 18 13 80 33 69
78 19 40 13 10 43 61 72 13 46
56 41 79 82 27 71 62 57 67 81
8 71 2 12 52 81 1 79 64 81
32 41 9 25 73 29 31 19 41 58
12 11 41 66 63 14 39 71 38 16
71 43 70 27 78 71 76 37 57 12
77 50 41 81 31 38 24 25 24 81
```

**Outputs**

```
(a) 9
(b) 9
(c) 8
```

### Winning

You may use any language. Shortest code wins.

Comment: Am I missing something, or are the sample inputs missing `m,n,k`?

Comment: @Geobits Oh, yes. I forgot to add it.

Comment: What exactly is a switchboard? How does it relate to this challenge?

Comment: I think the wording here is hard to digest. Let me say if I've understood right: You have a `m*n` grid of values, and a legal move consists of moving from a cell in the grid to another cell in the same row or column that has a strictly lower value. What is the minimum size `r` of a subset `S` of cells such that union of all length-`r` paths with start points in `S` covers the whole grid?

Comment: @xnor You're almost correct. Only thing that you missed out is that each path starts at a red cell, makes *less than or equal to k* turns and terminates. And every cell must be reachable by such a path.